# React js equivalent for ng-include

Tags: reactjs

i am using Reactjs. i want to include partial html in my view. something like ng-include.
what is the best way doing it?

```
<div>
    <ng-include src="myPageUrl"></ng-include>
</div>
```

i tried the following with no luck -- got

```
'Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: traverseAllChildren(...): 
Encountered an invalid child; 
DOM elements are not valid children of React components'
```

my code looks like this (based on http://benalpert.com/react/tips/initial-ajax.html)

```
var PageContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
   return {
    page: "loading page ..." 
   };
  },
  componentDidMount : function(){
   $.get(url, function(result) {
   var data = result;
   this.setState({
    page: data
   });
  }.bind(this));
 },
 render: function () {
  return (
    <div id="page" className="PageContainer">
        {this.state.page}
    </div>
 );
}
```

});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [React documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html):

> As a last resort, you always have the ability to insert raw HTML.
>
> `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'First &middot; Second'}} />`

So for you that could be:

```
render: function () {
  return (
    <div id="page" className="PageContainer"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.page}}
     >
    </div>
 );
```

Comment: would the inserted HTML be part of the virtual DOM and can it have ReactJS components?

Comment: The inserted HTML is not managed by React and it's considered to be plain regular HTML so it can't include React components. If you want to do anything more complex you'd have to parse the HTML and convert to React elements. There are libraries out there to help with that, for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react